# Vue - Cannot read property 0 of null in computed property V-for

Tags: vue.js

I'm using Vue's computed properties in order to create an array containing only data that I require from multiple arrays.

The issue is, when I'm cycling through the array with a V-for, I get the error of

```
Cannot read property '0' of null
```

This is even with me

- Setting a separate variable to say that the data is loaded (v-if="dataLoaded"), and therefore run the for loop
- Checking if the  length of the array is greater than zero (v-if="mappedUsers.length > 0) before running the for loop
- Checking if the variable exists(v-if="mappedUsers") before running the for loop.

html

```
<div v-if="mappedUsers">
     <tr v-for="(mappeduser, index) in mappedUsers" :key="mappeduser.uid">
       <td>{{mappeduser.uid}}</td>
       <td>{{mappeduser.email}}</td>
       <td>{{mappeduser.email}}</td>
       <td>{{mappeduser.email}}</td>
      <td>
         <select class="selectpicker" @change="changeRole(mappeduser.uid, $event)">
            <option :selected="mappeduser.role.superadmin" value="admin">SuperAdmin</option>
            <option :selected="mappeduser.role.admin" value="admin">Admin</option>
            <option :selected="mappeduser.role.customer" value="customer">Customer</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      <td><button type="button"  v-on:click="deleteUser(user.uid)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>
      <td>
         <span v-if="mappeduser.disabled === true"> <button type="button" v-on:click="enableUser(mappeduser.uid, index)" class="btn btn-success">Enable</button></span>
         <span v-if="mappeduser.disabled === false"><button type="button" v-on:click="disableUser(mappeduser.uid, index)" class="btn btn-primary">Disable</button></span>
      </td>
       <td><button type="button"  v-on:click="listAllUsers()"  class="btn btn-info">Reset Pwd</button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Reset Acnt</button></td>
      </tr>
  </div>
```

computed

```
omputed: {
    mappedUsers: function () {
      // map the user objects into one object in an  useable array
      const filteredArray = []
      for (let i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
        let newdata = []
        newdata.push(this.users[i], this.usersAuth[i])
        newdata = Object.assign(...newdata)
        filteredArray.push(newdata)
      }
      const filterElements = filteredArray.map((user) => {
        return ({ uid: user.id, email: user.email, disabled: user.disabled, role: user.role })
      })

      return filterElements
    }
  },
```

created

```
const addMessage = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('listAllUsers')
    addMessage()
      .then(result => {
        this.usersAuth = result.data.users
      })

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.user = user
    })

    this.users = []
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('roles')
      .get()
      .then(snap => {
        snap.forEach(doc => {
          const user = doc.data()
          user.id = doc.id
          this.users.push(user)
        })
      })
```

What am I doing wrong? checking the Vue Addon, mappedUsers returns correctly.

Comment: If I had to guess, the problem lies with `this.usersAuth[0]`. What is it? Prop, data, computed? Is it ever null? The rest of your code looks fine, except perhaps for not checking that `this.users` is an array.

Comment: Its an API call to firebase, which is done in created(). Ill updated the main post with information

Comment: The `created` hook doesn't wait for API calls, so you need to have a condition in your computed property to check that both `users` and `userAuth` were set.

Comment: mappedUsers is not being called in your for loop, it is a computed function that is run automatically by Vue.

Comment: so I cannot v-for on computed functions?

Comment: You can, but you need to write code that can compute and return a value at any possible state of the properties that it depends upon, including when those properties are null. e.g. `if (!Array.isArray(this.users) || !Array.isArray(this.userAuth)) return []`

Comment: So if I wrap the mappeduser v-for with  <div v-if="users && usersAuth"> as opposed to v-if="mappedUsers" it works! thanks for explaining it to me, much clearer now.

Comment: I suppose that will work if that is the only reference to `mappedUsers`. It would not need to be computed until `users && usersAuth`. That said, in a more complex application, you're better off moving that logic into the `computed` function.